# convergence or divergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^nu_{n}$

Tags: calculus

> Convergence or Divergence of series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

What i try

Using Leibnitz series test

$$u_{n+1}<u_{n}\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{(n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}<\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\;\forall n\geq 1$$

And $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}=0.$$

So we can say the series $$\sum (-1)^nu_{n}$$ is converges

Is my process is Right.if not please explain me

Also explain me some other way .Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course, you should define $u_n$ (it can be figured out but better to state it).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, though you could clean up your presentation a but. You could say that $\frac1{(n+1)^{3/2}}<\frac1{n^{3/2}}$, *therefore* the terms of the sequence monotonically decrease in magnitude (not the other way round).

The infinite sum may be more concisely written as $-\eta(3/2)$, where $\eta$ is [Dirichlet's eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are totally right. There is a another simple way,try I out.
Hint:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^p}$$
is convergent if $p\gt 1$

And an absolutely convergent series a convergent series..